# How do I make the code read from the array?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

```js
const array2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

function primeFactorsTo(num)
  {
  var store  = [], i, j, primes = [];
  for (i = 2; i <= num; ++i)
    {
    if (!store [i])
      {
      primes.push(i);
      for (j = i << 1; j <= num; j += i)
        {
        store[j] = true;
        }
      }
    }
```

Hi, I want the program to go through each number in `array2` and store the prime numbers in `primes[]`. I am doing self-study and am having a hard time implementing it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'add an array?'

Comment: I mean have the function go through the array

Comment: Which one? `array2`?

Comment: Yes, I want the program to go through the numbers in array 2 and output the prime factors for each number

Comment: Try `Array.forEach()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: title: `How do I make the code read from the array?` - body: `if there is a way to add the array to this` ... which is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function primeFactors(n) {
  const factors = [];
  let divisor = 2;

  while (n >= 2) {
    if (n % divisor == 0) {
      factors.push(divisor);
      n = n / divisor;
    } else {
      divisor++;
    }
  }
  return factors;
}
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
// Like this you can pass array to function
for(arrs of arr){
console.log(primeFactors(arrs))
}
```